# How to concatenate arrays from multiple documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say I have a collection called 'people' with the following documents:

```
{
    "name": "doug",
    "colors": ["blue", "red"]
}

{
    "name": "jack",
    "colors": ["blue", "purple"]
}

{
    "name": "jenny",
    "colors": ["pink"]
}
```

How would I get a concatenated array of all the `colors` subarrays, i.e.?

```
["blue", "red", "blue", "purple", "pink"]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to use aggregate:

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$colors"},
  {$group:{_id:null, clrs: {$push : "$colors"} }},
  {$project:{_id:0, colors: "$clrs"}}
])
```

Result:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "colors" : [
            "blue",
            "red",
            "blue",
            "purple",
            "pink"
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

**Updated**

If you want to get unique values in result's array, you could use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) operator instead of `$push` in the `$group` stage.

Comment: HI but if i need unique value in result how  i will achieve that as this will give duplicate entry in this array

Comment: For sure. To do this you could change `$push` operator with `$addToSet` in `{$group:{_id:null, clrs: {$push : "$colors"} }},` string.

Answer (score 34):

Well, Try should work fine for you!!

```
db.people.distinct("colors")
```

Comment: simple and efficient! this answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: very good, exactly what I needed; it is also good to know that you can pass an optional query to `distinct` to filter out the results. [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#specify-query-with-distinct)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This returns only the *distinct* colors, while the accepted answer returns all the arrays concatenated.