# Group documents and merge subdocuments arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group documents by a field and merge arrays of other fields.

Example: 
Source

```
[{
   "city": "NY",
   "size": [1,2,3,4,5],
   "tags": ["a","b","c","d"]
},
{
   "city": "NY",
   "size": [],
   "tags": ["c","d","z"]
},
{
   "city": "NY",
   "size": [1,2,10],
   "tags": []
}]
```

The array fields could also be arrays of subdocuments and can be empty or valued. I'm looking to group by name and merge the "size" and "tags" fields. 
So far I'm doing this:

```
aggregate({"$group":{
            _id: "$city",
            size: { "$addToSet": "$size"},
            tags: { "$addToSet": "$tags"}
        });
```

but it does not merge le arrays like I would like to. It returns;

```
{
   _id:"NY",
   size:[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,10]],
   tags:[["a","b","c","d"],["c","d","z"]]
}
```

And if I do an unwind on "size" and "tags" it just ignore the first and second document because one of their array is empty.

Here is what I wish to obtain:

```
{
    _id:"NY",
    size:[[1,2,3,4,5,10]].
    tags:["a","b","c","d","z"]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is a suggestion givin that kind of work but not quite (could be helpful for some)

Also here is the answer that someone proposed which kind of work but not quite

```
db.test.aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$city",
                    tags: {
                        "$addToSet": "$tags"
                    },
                    size: {
                        "$addToSet": "$size"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$tags"
            }, {
                $unwind: "$tags"
            }, {
                $unwind: "$size"
            }, {
                $unwind: "$size"
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    tags: {
                        "$addToSet": "$tags"
                    },
                    size: {
                        "$addToSet": "$size"
                    }
                }
            }
]);
```

Comment: A `$project` of `size: {$setUnion: '$size'}` would seem perfect for this, except for [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16281) which is curiously closed as 'works as designed'.

Comment: Yes I did see the setUnion that sounded promising but had no success with it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate arrays from multiple documents in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577109/how-to-concatenate-arrays-from-multiple-documents-in-mongodb)