# MongoDB Get concatenated values in a find method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDb. I've added some data to database like this:

> ```
> {
> "a1":[1,2,3,4,5],
> "b1":1
> "date":"Tue Apr 12 2016 15:34:21 GMT+0530 
> }
>
> {
> "a1":[11,12,13,14,15],
> "b1":2
> "date":"Tue Apr 12 2016 15:36:21 GMT+0530 
> }
> {
> "a1":[21,22,23,24,25],
> "b1":3
> "date":"Tue Apr 12 2016 15:38:21 GMT+0530 
> }
> ```

I need to get the concatenated values of field a1 b/w two date, and it also have an order.

i used a aggregate method json like this

```
[
    "$match":{ 
              "date": { 
                    "$gte":"Tue Apr 10 2016 15:34:27 GMT+0530 (IST)", 
                    "$lt": "Tue Apr 12 2016 15:34:27 GMT+0530 (IST)"
                  } 
             },
    {"$group":{"a1": {$push : "$l2"} }},

]
```

but it produce error.

I need output Like this:

> ```
> {
> "a1":[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25],
> "date":"Tue Apr 12 2016 15:38:21 GMT+0530 
> }
> ```

I'm using node.js. I need to know, is it possible in mongoDb?

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577109/how-to-concatenate-arrays-from-multiple-documents-in-mongodb